# Id e Produto ficando null quando salvo dados Many To One

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, postman

Sempre que tento criar uma Lista de itemPedido e usa-la em uma mapper para request, ela acaba como id e produto null. Já trackei com o debugger e ele não pega a referência com o idProduto que eu coloco no Postman. Sou novo nisso e estou certo que estou deixando passar algo.

O processo seria: Criar um Pedido que possui uma lista de itemPedido com os atributos Produto e quantidade. Mas o Produto fica como null.

Classe Pedido:

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pedido {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario_solicitante")
    private Usuario solicitante;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_endereco")
    private Endereco enderecoEntrega;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_estabelecimento", nullable = false)
    private Estabelecimento estabelecimento;

    @Valid
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pedido")
    private List<ItemPedido> itensPedido;

    @Valid
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FormaPagamento formaPagamento;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusPedido status;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime horarioSolicitacao;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime horarioSaiuParaEntrega;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime horarioEntrega;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime horarioCancelamento;

    private BigDecimal valorTotal;

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entregador")
    private Entregador entregador;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Usuario getSolicitante() {
        return solicitante;
    }

    public void setSolicitante(Usuario solicitante) {
        this.solicitante = solicitante;
    }

    public Endereco getEnderecoEntrega() {
        return enderecoEntrega;
    }

    public void setEnderecoEntrega(Endereco enderecoEntrega) {
        this.enderecoEntrega = enderecoEntrega;
    }

    public Estabelecimento getEstabelecimento() {
        return estabelecimento;
    }

    public void setEstabelecimento(Estabelecimento estabelecimento) {
        this.estabelecimento = estabelecimento;
    }

    public List<ItemPedido> getItensPedido() {
        return itensPedido;
    }

    public void setItensPedido(List<ItemPedido> itensPedido) {
        this.itensPedido = itensPedido;
    }

    public FormaPagamento getFormaPagamento() {
        return formaPagamento;
    }

    public void setFormaPagamento(FormaPagamento formaPagamento) {
        this.formaPagamento = formaPagamento;
    }

    public StatusPedido getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusPedido status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getHorarioSolicitacao() {
        return horarioSolicitacao;
    }

    public void setHorarioSolicitacao(LocalDateTime horarioSolicitacao) {
        this.horarioSolicitacao = horarioSolicitacao;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getHorarioSaiuParaEntrega() {
        return horarioSaiuParaEntrega;
    }

    public void setHorarioSaiuParaEntrega(LocalDateTime horarioSaiuParaEntrega) {
        this.horarioSaiuParaEntrega = horarioSaiuParaEntrega;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getHorarioEntrega() {
        return horarioEntrega;
    }

    public void setHorarioEntrega(LocalDateTime horarioEntrega) {
        this.horarioEntrega = horarioEntrega;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getHorarioCancelamento() {
        return horarioCancelamento;
    }

    public void setHorarioCancelamento(LocalDateTime horarioCancelamento) {
        this.horarioCancelamento = horarioCancelamento;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
        return valorTotal;
    }

    public void setValorTotal(BigDecimal valorTotal) {
        this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    }

    public Entregador getEntregador() {
        return entregador;
    }

    public void setEntregador(Entregador entregador) {
        this.entregador = entregador;
    }
}
```

Classe ItemPedido:

```
@Entity
public class ItemPedido {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_produto")
    private Produto produto;

    private Integer quantidade;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Produto getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }
}
```

Classe CriarPedidoRequest:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CriarPedidoRequest {

    private Long idPedido;
    private Long idEstabelecimento;
    private Long idUsuarioSolicitante;
    private Long idEnderecoEntrega;
    private List<ItemPedido> itens;
    private FormaPagamento formaPagamento;
    private StatusPedido status;
    private LocalDateTime horarioSolicitacao;
    private LocalDateTime horarioSaiuParaEntrega;
    private LocalDateTime horarioEntrega;
    private LocalDateTime horarioCancelamento;
    private BigDecimal valorTotal;
    private Long idEntregador;
    private Long idProduto;
    private Integer quantidade;
}
```

Classe CriarPedidoService:

```
@Service
public class CriarPedidoService {

    @Autowired
    private PedidoRepository pedidoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CriarPedidoMapper criarPedidoMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemPedidoRepository itemPedidoRepository;

    public Pedido salvarPedido(CriarPedidoRequest request) {

        Pedido pedido = criarPedidoMapper.mapear(request);
        pedido.setStatus(StatusPedido.EM_PREPARO);
        pedido.setHorarioSolicitacao(LocalDateTime.now());

        Produto produto = produtoRepository.findById(request.getIdProduto()).get();

        List<ItemPedido> itens = new ArrayList<>();
        ItemPedido itemPedido = new ItemPedido();

        itemPedido.setProduto(produto);
        itemPedido.setQuantidade(request.getQuantidade());
        itens.add(itemPedido);

        pedido.setItensPedido(itens);

        return pedidoRepository.save(pedido);
    }
}
```

CriarPedidoMapper:

```
@Component
public class CriarPedidoMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EnderecoRepository enderecoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EstabelecimentoRepository estabelecimentoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntregadorRepository entregadorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemPedidoRepository itemPedidoRepository;


    public Pedido mapear(CriarPedidoRequest request) {

        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository
                .findById(request.getIdUsuarioSolicitante()).get();

        Endereco enderecoEntrega = enderecoRepository
                .findById(request.getIdEnderecoEntrega()).get();

        Estabelecimento estabelecimento = estabelecimentoRepository
                .findById(request.getIdEstabelecimento()).get();

        Entregador entregador = entregadorRepository
                .findById(request.getIdEntregador()).get();

        Produto produto = produtoRepository
                .findById(request.getIdProduto()).get();

        BigDecimal valor = produto.getValor();
        Integer quantidade = request.getQuantidade();
        BigDecimal valorTotal = BigDecimal.valueOf(quantidade).multiply(valor);



        return new Pedido(request.getIdPedido(), usuario, enderecoEntrega, estabelecimento, request.getItens(),
                request.getFormaPagamento(), request.getStatus(), request.getHorarioSolicitacao(),
                request.getHorarioSaiuParaEntrega(), request.getHorarioEntrega(),
                request.getHorarioCancelamento(), valorTotal, entregador);
    }
}
```

Json:

```
{
    "idEstabelecimento": 1,
    "idUsuarioSolicitante": 1,
    "idEnderecoEntrega": 1,
    "formaPagamento": "PIX",
    "itens": [
        {
            "idProduto": 1,
            "quantidade": 1
        },
        {
            "idProduto": 2,
            "quantidade": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu método de serviço não está anotado com `@Transactional`, dessa forma as operações não são executadas dentro de um **bloco transactional**.

```
@Transactional
public Pedido salvarPedido(CriarPedidoRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

Como você está utilizando Spring, atente-se para utilizar [a anotação do Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

### Mas o que um bloco transacional faz?

Primeiro vamos entender os estados de um objeto, que podem ser `Persistent`, `Transient` ou `Detached`, e são descritos [nessa parte da documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview).

Quando você não especifíca que seu método todo será parte de um bloco transacional, suas alterações são tratadas de forma separada.

Caso você defina um bloco transacional (declarando `@Transactional` em seu método), os objetos carregados nesse bloco serão persistentes, e ao finalizar o bloco, as alterações nesses objetos serão identificadas e comitadas.

> It might just have been saved or loaded, however, it is by definition
> in the scope of a Session. Hibernate will detect any changes made to
> an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the
> database when the unit of work completes.